# Really small reply screen on mobile

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, mobile-web, design

On my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge which has a screen width of 360px, the input box for replying to someone on Jobs is really small. It is unfit to type a proper reply on mobile.

Can there be a full screen button to expand the input box to 100vw and 100vh?

[image: really small input box]

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland I would have typed the same message I eventually did on a laptop. I just ended up using an editor on my mobile and then pasting it into the answer box after review and peer review.

Comment: Doesn't that page have a mobile view?

Comment: @Cerbrus is that not the mobile page we see though not done well? Tschallacka: The number of tabs you have open gives me anxiety... That shouldn't be legal!

Comment: @Script47 Good for me that it isn't illegal

Comment: @Script47 A lot of us are at a constant ":D" which means you have more than 99. Why care about tabs you don't care about? (And no, it's not slowing anything down)

Comment: @DavidMulder There is a "close all tabs" button, if you don't care about the tabs, why leave them open?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton because closing them takes two more tabs than not closing them.

Comment: @DavidMulder If you say so.